# bootstrap in rails -- no bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ruby on rails app. I added bootstrap to it using `bootstrap-sass` gem and following the instructions at:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

However, I think some of the bootstrap styling are not imported. For example using `class=panel` is not doing anything. Also, when I `View page source` in the browser, I can't see any such line as

```
<link data-turbolinks-track='true' href='/assets/bootstrap.css'>
```

My solution was to copy `bootstrap.css` into the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder. Is that how it should be done or I there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-sass approach:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

I used this gem which also has a Railscast associated with it to use Twitter Bootstrap within my Rails app.

Otherwise to manually configure bootstrap, changing href to href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" should do the trick. Make sure to include jQuery links as well.